# Repository Pattern and Model Relationships and Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, sharepoint, dependency-injection, repository-pattern

Im quite new to the use of the repository pattern and I'm struggling how to achieve relationships in my models while using repositories. So for example I have the following two repository interfaces: `IPersonRepository` and `IAddressRepository`

```
public interface IPersonRepository
{
    IList<Person> GetAll();
    Person GetById(int id);
}

public interface IAddressRepository
{
    IList<Address> GetAll();
    Address GetById(int id);
    Address GetByPerson(Person person);
}
```

And two model classes: `Person` and `Address`

```
public class Person
{
    private IAddressRepository _addressRepository;

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    private Address _address;
    public Address Address
    {
        get { return _addressRepository.GetByPerson(this); }
        set { _address = value; }
    }

    Person(string firstName, string lastName, IAddressRepository addressRepository)
    {
        this.FirstName = firstName;
        this.LastName = lastName;
        this._addressRepository = addressRepository;
    }
}

public class Address
{
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Zip { get; set; }
    public List<Person> Persons { get; set; }

    Address(string street, string city, string zip)
    {
        this.Street = street;
        this.City = city;
        this.Zip = zip;
    }
}
```

So now my question is: Is it fine to inject an `IAddressRepository` into the `Person` class and request the actual address by lazy loading it from the getter in the actual `Person` object? Additionally, would I Inject the `IPersonRepository` into the `Address` object if it has a method like `GetPersons()`? I'm asking this because I'm refactoring some code to use the repository pattern  and want to make use of dependency injection to prepare it to be better testable at a later point.

Additionally: I'm not using any ORM as I am developing in a SharePoint Environment and I'm using SharePoint Lists as the actual data storage for the Domain Models.

Comment: It seems extremely odd to have a reference to the repository within the object itself. What is the reasoning behind doing this?

Comment: Well, i think I just don't know how to do better. :) How would you build the relationship to the `Address` while supporting lazy loading from the data storage?

Comment: You are trying to do what EF already does for you. EF generates proxy classes to inject additional code to be used in case of lazy loading.
Check **[this](http://www.alachisoft.com/resources/articles/entity-framework-poco-lazy-loading.html)** article and see if it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

If I was doing this myself, I would not inject the repository into your models.

Instead, on the Address model, I would have a personId field, or if you are tracking more than one person per address, a collection of personIds.

Doing this, you could have a method on your address repository named `GetByPersonId(int personId)` which would then fetch the address for that person by checking if the id of the person matched the id on the address or the id collection on the address contained the personId passed in.

Comment: Correct me if I get this wrong, but would using a method called `GetByPersonId(int personId)` make any difference? I still would need some kind of reference to the `AddressRepository` inside the `Person` objects `Address` getter to receive the actual address.

Comment: It would not have to be inside the person no. You could have it on the person, but having repositories injected into your entities is not really nice and clean. Myself, wherever it was needed, I would fetch a person, and then when I needed the address, call the method on the repository directly using the ID from the person. For example, if you were doing it in an MVC controller, I would inject both repositories into the controller, and make the calls when necessary.

Comment: Okay I got this, but when I request the address manually using the repository I could omit the `Address` property and there would be no lazy loading support of a `Person`s address. Is there any other way with the navigation property?